# Asynchronous / Synchronous Looping Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

Hi I'm trying to do something a little weird here it's kind of mixing async and sync together hence why it's not working how I expected. Currently runs for 3 users from the array then ends how would I get this to run for the entire length of the usernames in the array?

```
var i = 0,
fs = require('fs'),
fetch = require('node-fetch');

fs.readFile('file.txt', function(err, data) {
  var array = data.toString().split("\n");
  getCreationDate(array);
});

function getCreationDate(array) {
  fetch('http://mytwitterbirthday.com/api/?screen_name=' + array[i])
  .then(function(res) {
    return res.json();
  }).then(function(json) {
    console.log(i, array[i])
    console.log(json[0].screen_name, json[0].created_at);
  }).then(function() {
    i++;
    getCreationDate(array);
  })
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you don't need to print the outputs in the same order as in the array. In this case you can change `getCreationDate()` to accept a single name and its index.

```
function getCreationDate(name, i) {
  fetch('http://mytwitterbirthday.com/api/?screen_name=' + name)
  .then(function(res) {
    var json = res.json();
    console.log(i, name)
    console.log(json[0].screen_name, json[0].created_at);
  });
}
```

Now call the above function for each item in the array.

```
array.forEach(getCreationDate);
```

Comment: Note: This will launch all the requests at once (in parallel - whereas the original code was doing them serially if that matters for rate limiting) and code would have to be added to either obtain the result in order or to know when all the results are done.  This is not really useful by itself - only a piece of a solution.

Comment: That's not a `Queue consumer`, it runs each request at once.

Comment: @Hitmands: Yes, I mentioned in the answer that: "I assume you don't need to print the outputs in the same order as in the array."

Answer (score 0):

Probably that could help...
You missed a catch.

```js
const 
  fs = require('fs'),
  fetch = require('node-fetch')
;

(new Promise((res, rej) => {
  fs.readFile('file.txt', (err, data) => {
    if(err) {
      return rej(err);
    }
    
    return resolve(data.toString().split('\n'));
  });  
}))
  .then(data => doSomething(data, 0))
  .catch(error => console.error.bind(console))
;

function doSomething(data, index) {
  const API = 'http://mytwitterbirthday.com/api/';
  const MAX_ERRORS = 3; // or what you want
  let errors = 0;
  
  return fetch(`${API}?screen_name=${data[index]}`)
    .then(r => r.json())
    .then(response => {
      console.log("response", response);
    })
    .then(() => doSomething(data, ++index))
    .catch(error => {
      if(MAX_ERRORS <= errors) {
        console.log('giving up', {errors});
        return;
      }
      
      errors += 1;
      return doSomething(data, index);
    })
  ;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I will add another answer because the accepted answer does not provide the following:

1. Notification when all the requests are done
2. Provide results in order
3. Error handling
4. Any concurrency control to decide how many requests run at the same time (may be important for twitter rate limiting)

This first solution uses the Bluebird promise library because it simplifies things significantly. particularly for concurrency control:

```
const Promise = require('bluebird');
const fs = Promise.promsifyAll(require('fs'));
const fetch = require('node-fetch);

function getSingleCreationDate(item) {
    return fetch('http://mytwitterbirthday.com/api/?screen_name=' + item).then(function(response) {
        return response.json();
    });
}

function getAllCreationDates(file) {
    return fs.readFileAsync(file).then(function(data) {
        let array = data.toString().split("\n");
        // put whatever concurrency value here works best, higher is more parallelism
        // lower is more protection from being rate limited by the host
        return Promise.map(array, getSingleCreationDate, {concurrency: 4});
    });
}

getAllCreationDates('file.txt').then(function(results) {
    // process array of results here (in order)
}).catch(function(err) {
    // handle error here
});
```

This second solution uses standard ES6 promises and serializes the requests like the OP's original code:

```
const fs = require('fs');
const fetch = require('node-fetch);

// promisify readFile
fs.readFileAsync = function(file, options) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        fs.readFile(file, options, function(err, data) {
            if (err) return reject(err);
            resolve(data);
        });
    });
}

function getSingleCreationDate(item) {
    return fetch('http://mytwitterbirthday.com/api/?screen_name=' + item).then(function(response) {
        return response.json();
    });
}

function getAllCreationDates(file) {
    return fs.readFileAsync(file).then(function(data) {
        let array = data.toString().split("\n");
        let results = [];
        return array.reduce(function(p, item) {
            return p.then(function() {
                return getSingleCreationDate(item).then(function(twitterData) {
                    results.push(twitterData);
                });
            })
        }, Promise.resolve()).then(function() {
            // make array of results be the resolved value
            return results;
        });
    });
}

getAllCreationDates('file.txt').then(function(results) {
    // process array of results here (in order)
}).catch(function(err) {
    // handle error here
});
```

Or, if twitter is fine with you sending all the requests at once, you can do this:

```
const fs = require('fs');
const fetch = require('node-fetch);

// promisify readFile
fs.readFileAsync = function(file, options) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        fs.readFile(file, options, function(err, data) {
            if (err) return reject(err);
            resolve(data);
        });
    });
}

function getSingleCreationDate(item) {
    return fetch('http://mytwitterbirthday.com/api/?screen_name=' + item).then(function(response) {
        return response.json();
    });
}

function getAllCreationDates(file) {
    return fs.readFileAsync(file).then(function(data) {
        let array = data.toString().split("\n");
        return Promise.all(array.map(function(item) {
            return getSingleCreationDate(item);
        }));
    });
}

getAllCreationDates('file.txt').then(function(results) {
    // process array of results here (in order)
}).catch(function(err) {
    // handle error here
});
```